# How do I get the correct forestplot with each variable with its categories, indicating the reference variable and the values of those that are not

Tags: hazard, forest-plot

When doing the Coxph analysis with the variables selected from an excel file, it gives a numerical result indicating the HR of each one of them according to the reference one. However, when I represent it with the ggforest function, the graph I get is the following (all the categories of all the variables are shown as a reference and their HR value is not shown). How can I solve this?

datos <- read.xlsx("D:/Linfoma Hodgkin/Forest_Excel.xlsx", "1", "Hoja4")

model <- coxph( Surv(OS, Event) ~ Sex + Age + B.symptoms + Ratio, data=datos)

ggforest(model, datos)

[image]